# Insert Beamer Frame before the first Frame in Lyx

Tags: beamer, lyx

In Lyx2.1.2.2, I have created a Beamer frame. Now I want to add a new Frame before the first Frame, but I am lost about how to do it. I don't want to delete it and create a new one again.

Is it possible to add a new Frame before the first frame in Lyx?